# C# call WCF service over https using certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, pfx

I have  WCF service worked over https. This WCF service  required private certificate and sing on password I have proper certificate and password. Certificate have been installed into repository.

I can't retrive wsdl xml  document from this web service.
What I tried to do:

- Calling WebService using  IE,FireFox,Chrome, etc.
  Every time I got:
  *"XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource 'https://ServiceHostHere:453/ServiceMethodhere...."*
- Discovering WebService uning VS2010 Add Service Reference,I got:
  *The document at the url https://ServiceNameHere:453/ServiceMethod/Service.svc?wsdl was not recognized as a known document type.
  The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

  - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Root element is missing.'.
  - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Root element is missing.'.
  - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (0, 0).'.*

**Only "SOAP UI" tool works fine current with service.**

Comment: Are you sure the SOAPUI tool can retrieve the WSDL? It sounds to me like the WCF metadata endpoint is not configured correctly or is just plain old broken.

Comment: The only time I've seen `top level element` error is when I accidentally typed some characters at the top of the config file :)

Comment: The issue was solved. Thank you
url is case sensetive, so I just copied right url and everything is fine now